# How to hide two Windows installations from each other?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, bitlocker, veracrypt

I have Windows 11 Pro and Windows 10 Pro installed side by side on the same computer. (Why? Because reasons.) Requirements are that 11 must be running Bitlocker, and SecureBoot must be enabled (due to Windows 11).

I want to hide those two Windows installations so that they can't see each other in any meaningful way.

With W11 this is already in order thanks to Bitlocker, you can't see W11 files from the W10 installation, even though 10 has assigned a drive letter D: for the W11 partition. The D: drive appears "locked" from W10. However in W11 you can see the contests of the unencrypted W10 partition as a D: drive.

Things I've tried:

1. I enabled Bitlocker also on W10. This caused some odd problem that I could not boot to the W10 at all anymore. It would repeatedly ask for the W10 Bitlocker recovery key and even if I typed it in correctly (it didn't say it is a wrong key which it does if you mistype something), the machine reboots itself and it asks for the recovery key again and again, until complaining it has been given too many times and the W10 installation must be "fixed". I fixed it by removing the W10 partitions and reinstalling W10 from the scratch again.
2. Next I tried VeraCrypt in W10 instead, and used the option to encrypt the system partition. In the VC options it asked whether this is a multiboot system, I said yes because it is.

After the encryption, I would have to enter the W11 Bitlocker recovery key every time I wanted to boot to W11. It would boot successfully to it, but always require that recovery key, as if something always changed in the machine configuration when booting to W11. I booted back to W10 and told VC to decrypt the W10 system partition, and now W11 doesn't ask for the recovery key repeatedly anymore.

What I didn't quite understand was that VeraCrypt asks for the encryption password already before getting to the Windows menu where you select to which Windows installation you want to boot to. I was expecting it would ask for that only after you select W10 from that boot menu. Should I have selected "Single OS installation" during the VeraCrypt installation instead?

3. The third option I tried was to leave W10 unencrypted, but in W11 remove the drive letter D: from the W10 partition with Disk Management. Now the W10 partition is not easily seen on the W11 side in File Explorer etc... but can and will e.g. virus scanners and other scanning software still inspect that partition for its files? I don't necessarily need to hide the partition from other people (as I am the only user on this laptop), but so that W11 virus scanners and such would always ignore the W10 partition and its files.

I am not that concerned that e.g. the W10 partition would be infected by a virus from W11 installation, as the W11 installation is kept secure, so encrypting the W10 partition (and make it unreachable from W11 that way) is not necessarily needed, if there is another way to tell W11 and all its utilities (virus scanners and such) "Ignore that partition altogether, nothing for you to see there.".

Comment: Most scanning software acts on drive letters or network shares. Never seen that a software enumerates partitions/volumes and tries to access them directly or mounting it. I assume a virtualized W10 environment is not an option for you as you already put a lot of effort into finding a solution for a parallel installation.

Comment: Ok I guess I will continue with the current setup where I've just removed the drive letter in Windows 11 so that it doesn't see the Windows 10 partition as a D: drive.

Virtual machines is not an option as the Win10 installation is used also for games and stuff. Unless virtualization has improved so much lately that they utilize GPUs fully etc... In that case Win10 as a virtual machine might be even preferable.

Comment: I have described the process of bitlocking two installations side by side here: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33649/Bitlocker-and-multi-booting.html

It's rather straight forward and works as expected (bitlock installation 1 then bitlock the 2nd, each with its own PIN), so I will not layout the steps here again but rather advise you to refer to the screenshots over there if you are feeling unsure during the process. After bitlocking, you should rename the boot options using bcdedit.exe to something meaningful so that you can tell one from the other.